# Can I publish iPhone / iPad apps using anything other than the Apple SDK?

Tags: ios, app-store

Is is possible to use RealBasic/Java/Ruby or any other languages to publish to the iPhone/iPad, or am I locked into Apple's tools only? It would be good to see examples of where this has been done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like http://rhomobile.com for Ruby maybe? For Html/Javascript you have Nimblekit, PhoneGap, Titanium etc. There are a growing number of frameworks out there now that offer similar features and capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago Apple removed restriction on usage of foreign tools. However, anyway you will need a gate to translate your language calls into native Obejctive C function calls.

Comment: Are there any good examples of apps that have been written this way?

Answer (score 1):

Check [MonoTouch](http://monotouch.net/) - seems to be a good option